# Union on one column in SQL

Tags: sql, union

I have scenario where I need to union results based on one column

Table 1

```
Name   Rank  
------------
A1     1    
A2     6
```

Table 2

```
Name    Rank  
------------
A1      3  
A3      4
```

Now I need the union of distinct names sorted based on ranks.

Result should be

```
Name  
-----
A1   
A3   
A2
```

Could you help me with the SQL query to get this result?

Comment: And what do you do if same name appears in 2 tables? How do you rank them in that case? Take lowest, highest, or?

Comment: Also, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: A1 apears twice and take lowest one

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to order by max rank.

```
Select Name from (
    Select Name,Rank
    From Table1
    Union
    Select Name,Rank
    From Table2
) T
group by Name
order by max(Rank)
```

---

[DEMO TEST LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=5faf03cf3eb935d7cc175c1dac0e3d5a)

---

**Result:**

```
Name  
-----
A1   
A3   
A2
```

Comment: I have tried this.But this gives the duplicate rows. I need the unique rows

Comment: try again . I group by name , it'll get unique rows